# Удаление и редактирование ячеек MySQL через PHP [Location - проблема]

Tags: xhtml, php, html, html5, mysql

Есть код (таблица вывода оборудования) есть ф-ии редактирования и удаления опред. строки (ID), и есть такое место в коде, что после выполненного действия надо вернуться на предыдущую страницу:

```
header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
```

Но все знают, что перед этим выражением не должно быть пустых строк или HTML кода, но дело в том, что мне НАДО вставить HTML код перед выводом таблицы. Как только я ставлю HTML код, выскакивает ошибка:

```
 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\adminka\devices.php:11) in C:\AppServ\www\adminka\devices.php on line 327
```

Вопрос: как быть? HTML код ОЧЕНЬ нужно вставить перед эти выводом

Answer (score 1):

не вижу вариантов когда надо слать html код если вы хотите перейти на другую страницу. Есть вариант что вы пишите html вместе с логикой тогда вам поможет только буферизация вывода через ob_start(); $str = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();
Но вообще разделяйте логику и шаблон меньше теряться будете.

```
ob_start();
if ( !isset( $_GET["action"] ) ) $_GET["action"] = "showlist";
switch ( $_GET["action"] )
{
  case "showlist":    // Список всех записей в таблице БД
    show_list(); break;
  case "editform":    // Форма для редактирования записи
    get_edit_row_form(); break;
  case "update":      // Обновить запись в таблице БД
    update_row(); break;
  case "delete":      // Удалить запись в таблице БД
    delete_row(); break;
  default:
    show_list();
}
$str = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php');
echo $str;
```

как то так приблизительно.

Answer (score 0):

а зачем это делать? Location вас моментально должен отправить на указанную страницу, отсюда вопрос -- зачем ДО этого чтото выводить, если пользователь этого не увидит.
если ооочень сильно надо, то сделайте редирект через `javascript`.

---

кажется я понял) вы хотите ПОСЛЕ редактирования/удаления редирект сделать?
тогда так, если после редактирования/удаления ничего не надо выводить и просто применить действие, то пользуйтесь ее можно использовать сразу после выполнения каких то действий типа, которые расположить в самом начале:

```
<? if (!empty($_GET['submit-info'])) {
//чтото делаем, но ничего на экран не выводим
header("Location: blahblah.php");
}
?>
//тут дальше вывод чеголибо если `empty($_GET['submit-info'])`
```

если надо чтото выводить, то только яваскриптом лучше всего будет...

Comment: Вы непоняли. Мне надо прописать шапку сайта со стилями, а если я это начинаю писать, но при редактировании или удалении пишется эта ошибка. Так как перед этой функцией не должно быть строк!

Comment: так а зачем эта функция на этой странице? очень кажется, что либо вы не понимаете что делает эта функция либо вы чтото другое хотите сделать, только не правильно формулируете вопрос :) весь код или его часть с действиями была бы очень кстати :)